# Should I use past simple or present perfect in that context?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple

I am confused, while solving random questions to enhance my understanding of past simple and present perfect, I was stuck in the following question:

> My sister .................... engineering for five years and became a clever engineer.
> [studied - has studied]

I've answered it "has studied" because it's something that happened in the past and has consequences in the present "became a clever engineer". I am not sure if that's correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence says *became*, which is not the present (although she may still be an engineer).

The perfect tense would be more appropriate if the studies were recent.

> My sister has studied engineering for five years and is now fully qualified.

Answer (score 0):

The term "has" connotes past modes of being. *John has worked as a waiter, a mechanic, and a circus clown.* Leaving out "has" instead connotes an action - which, in your example, would be more naturally depict the flow of time. *I bought the ingredients and read the cookbooks, so now I'm ready to make dinner*.